# Delegating events to a specific descendant using .on() in jQuery

Tags: jquery

In a rails/jQuery app, I want to dynamically append a new `select` tag to an ever-growing list, whenever the user selects something from the **last** dropdown.

I was going to use `live()`, but discovered that it's been deprecated, so I turned to `.on()` and [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

The following code gets properly triggered when changing the value of *any* select tag that descends from `#list_of_selects`:

```
$("#list_of_selects").on("change", "select", function() {
  alert("Found!")
});
```

But again, I only want to take action when the **last** dropdown in the list is acted upon. The following event delegation, however, does not get triggered, and I suspect I am missing something relevant on how selectors work.

```
$("#list_of_selects").on("change", "select:last", function() {
  alert("Found!")
});
```

If I replace `"select:last"` with `$("select:last")` then the event is *always* triggered

Comment: Can you provide a `jsFiddle`?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/nyR7q/ - Works fine for me. Conflicting code somewhere else?

That said, I'd recommend something like this instead: http://jsfiddle.net/2F3yn/

Instead of listening to the entire div for changes then filtering to the last one, just listen for changes on the last one directly.

Comment: Joe, you are right that the problem was a rather obscure conflict (which may deserve a question in its own right), but the alternative proposal would not work, as it will not recognize as the last item a dynamically appended select. I am not sure about the rules, but if you edit your answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

i fix Joe variant for your case [link](http://jsfiddle.net/deerua/2F3yn/1/)